# Postgres grant issue on select from view, but not from base table

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds-aurora

I have a problem I can't work out.  I am using the postgres account on my instance, and I have some failures in selecting from a view, where can select against the base table fine.

Let me run through a log of what I did, regranting explicitly anything that may be missing.

I can select from the table, but not from the view, with ERROR: 42501

```
deals2=> select count(*) from schema1.a1a_table1 where 1 = 0;
ERROR:  42501: permission denied for table table1
LOCATION:  aclcheck_error, aclchk.c:3554
deals2=> select count(*) from schema1.table1 where 1 = 0;
 count
-------
     0
(1 row)

deals2=> grant connect on database deals2 to postgres;
GRANT
deals2=> grant usage on schema schema1 to postgres;
GRANT
deals2=> grant select on schema1.table1 to postgres;
GRANT
deals2=> grant select on schema1.a1a_table1 to postgres;
GRANT
deals2=> select * from schema1.a1a_table1 where 1 = 0;
ERROR:  42501
```

The view is defined as:

```
-- View definition of schema1.a1a_table1

 SELECT schema1.book,
    schema1.deal_number,
    schema1.parent,
    schema1.child,
    schema1.deal_date,
    -- etc
FROM schema1.table1;
```

I think I know my databases quite well and can't really figure this one out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check who the owner of the table and the view are, and what permissions are set on each.

Unless you defined the view with `security_invoker = on` (from v15 on), the permissions on `table1` are checked with the owner of `a1a_table`. So you'd have to grant that owner the `SELECT` privilege on `table1` for the view to work.

If the view has `security_invoker = on`, the user who uses the view must have the `SELECT` privilege.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html#id-1.9.3.97.7) describes that in detail.